# Best display / editing of subcategories (use Tree ASP.NET or VB.NET winform control?)

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net

I've got a categories table, and sub-category tables 3 levels deep (in the database they're called Categories, SubCategories, SubSubCategories, and SubSubSubCategories).

On the presentation side, I am curious what the best way is to manage those.  The categories form a tree/hierarchy structure, so a tree control of some kind sounds useful.  Drag-and-drop functionality would be nice.  This can be done in a VB.NET 3.5 web application (preferred) or VB.NET Windows application.

Any thoughts on the best way to handle this?  It looks like the TreeView doesn't support drag-and-drop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the TreeView control for standard VB.NET applications instead of the WPF TreeView. If I had more time, the WPF TreeView seems much more powerful.